# Any update on OWIN in IIS take best of both world?

Tags: iis, owin, .net-framework-version

As working on converting .NET Core web api to .NET Framework, I had options of couple different ways of achieveing it and I end up reading below links and decide to go with OWIN in IIS.

Difference between OWIN and IIS
[ASP.NET Web API 2 hosting differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806039/asp-net-web-api-2-hosting-differences)

Getting started with OWIN in IIS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana#host-owin-in-iis

Before I actually put myself into this route,  would there be any new updates on .NET Framework  (not .NET Core) which beats this solution make it look old?

Comment: "As working on converting .NET Core web api to .NET Framework". When you go against the tide, you will find it abandoned. So clearly there is going to be no change at all except security patches.

Comment: yup I am with you but this restriction is set by legacy framework and my app is mere plugin to it.